# sinatra sending headers and body

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm posting from a web contact form to sinatra. Which works perfectly. I need to set custom headers because it's a CORS request which works also perfect.

But when I want to return a reply json to the request for :status and :message I seem to send a sinatra object and not proper json.

Also I the message is not in the body but in the header if I see the print out in my log.

Snippet of the code:

```
    headers \
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" => "POST",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" =>  "Content-Type",
      "Access-Control-Max-Age" => "86400"

    if params[:email].empty?
      response[:status] = "error"
      response[:message] = "No email"
      p response.inspect
      body response.to_json
    elsif params[:mailbody].empty?
      response[:status] = "error"
      response[:message] = "No message?"
      body response.to_json
    elsif

...
```

The log file:

```
"#<Sinatra::Response:0x007fc62bfed2f8 @status=200, @header={\"Content-Type\"=>\"application/json\", \"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\"=>\"*\", \"Access-Control-Allow-Methods\"=>\"POST\", \"Access-Control-Allow-Headers\"=>\"Content-Type\", \"Access-Control-Max-Age\"=>\"86400\", :status=>\"error\", :message=>\"No email\"}, @chunked=false, @writer=#<Proc:0x007fc62bfecf88@/Users/gtheys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/response.rb:27 (lambda)>, @block=nil, @length=0, @body=[]>"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Aug/2014 10:48:57] "POST / " 200 39 0.0077
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

remove:

```
response[:status] = "error"
response[:message] = "No email"
```

Add:

```
{:status => "error", :message => "No email"}.to_json
```

And it works